# How to display a default image if the image file path stored in database does not exist?

Tags: php, html

I would like to ask help as to how I can display a default image in case the image file path I stored in my database does not exist. I have gone through links to see if it could help me with my query but it didn't work.

The least I was able to do was this:

```
<?php
        $con = new mysqli("localhost" ,"root" ,"" ,"user_databases");

        $iquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT map_image_filepath FROM buildings");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($iquery))
        {
          echo "<img src='".$row['map_image_filepath']."'>";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Where "map_image_filepath" is the column name from my buildings table where the file paths are stored.

I really have no idea what to do next. I hope you guys could help :(

Comment: check if path is real with `file_exists($filename)` else echo something else

Comment: Hi Richard, tried adding that. However, I get this error, "Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path" and below it displays the default image because the image file path I added in my table does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look my example:

```
<?php
        $con = new mysqli("localhost" ,"root" ,"" ,"user_databases");

        $iquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT map_image_filepath FROM buildings");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($iquery))
        {

    $filename = $row['map_image_filepath'].".png";//here you can put jpg also
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "<img src="{$filename}">";
    }else{
        echo "<img src="NoImage.jpg">";
    }

}

        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked :) However, why do two default images show?

Comment: Check extension or correct path for uploaded image.
You can change from ".png" to ".jpg"
Or you have complete file on database (including extension), you can delete "  .".png"  "

Comment: Oh yeah I overlooked it. Thank you so much for the great help! :D